# how to trigger a double click on a single click using jquery

Tags: jquery, events

Is it possible to trigger double click on user's single click? note that I want the same behaviour as it was double clicked by using mouse, Is it possible to get the same behaviour using jQuery? What I've tried so far :

```
$("#container").dblclick(function() { 
    //code executed on jQuery double click rather than mouse double click
});
$("#container").click(function() { 
    $(this).dblclick(); 
});
```

When I double click using mouse it goes right, it generate the right result I want, but when I try to do it with jQuery, it does not seem to be working, please Help! Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Why not just put the logic in an external function and call that function from both event handlers? I'm at a loss to understand why you'd want to always trigger a double click on a single click, though

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, sometimes you are using a 3rd party module and you want to trigger events on elements that created by that module.

Comment: What is the behaviour of `mouse double click` you are talking about? Share a minimalistic sample replicating your issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure where exactly your problem is, but this code works exactly as expected:

```js
$("#container").dblclick(function() { 
  //code executed on jQuery double click rather than mouse double click
  alert('dblclick');
});
$("#container").click(function() { 
  alert('click');
  $(this).dblclick(); 
});

$("#container2").click(function() { 
  $("#container").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">click 1</div>
<div id="container2">click 2</div>
```

If you click on 'click 1' - you will have the 2 alerts (the original and the dblclick).
If you click on 'click 2' - the jquery will trigger the `click` on the first element, which will trigger 2 alerts (the `click` and the `dblclick`).

Answer (score 0):

Just an update on why. I use agent ransack and if I can launch it with a double-click I get two instances of the program. I can use different search parameters on each.