# Change single click as double click to specific element (e.g 'a')

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to change single click as double click to specific element like tag "a".

Comment: This is not a question but a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("a").click(function(){
$(this).dblclick(alert("Hello World!"));
});
  });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Double Click event</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <a href="#">Double click here</a>
  </body>
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest example of `dblclick()`:

```js
$("a").dblclick(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("Hello World!");
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#'>Double click here</a>
```

Comment: Thank for you answer. But I mean I don't want to click double. I just want to click single and effect like double. :)

Comment: Can you explain more on what do you mean by `effect like double`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#element_id").click(function() { 
      $(this).dblclick(); 
    });
```

[how to trigger a double click on a single click using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723960/how-to-trigger-a-double-click-on-a-single-click-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    $(this).dblclick(alert("Double click worked!"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">Double click here</a>
```

Check this once.