# how to make dbClick with querySelector?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to make double click programmatically something like

```
 document.querySelector("button").blur()
```

but for double click, because `document.querySelector("button").dblclick()` isnt working...

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: same sort of question has been posted please try that
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723960/how-to-trigger-a-double-click-on-a-single-click-using-jquery

Comment: @TharikKanaka apart from `jQuery` isn't tagged in this question and the one you have posted is using `jQuery`

Comment: @NewToJS document.querySelector(...).dblclick is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Try this to emit double click event:

```
var dbclickEvent = new MouseEvent('dblclick', {
   bubble: true,
   view: window
})

document.querySelector('button').dispatchEvent(dbclickEvent)
```

Answer (score -1):

One useful method of event is the preventDefault() method. preventDefault() will prevent whatever the browser would have done automatically when, say, a double click occurred.

```
 var button= document.querySelector('button');
 button.addEventListener('dblclick', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
},false);
```

Comment: Are you going to explain your answer or do you plan to just dump the source code and hope the OP does some research to understand what is happening within your source code? Although the source code might be good, answers like this can still be down voted for not being detailed/explained as it isn't very helpful to some who might want to use it....

Comment: I am also self-taught but I also ensure I have a clear understanding of the functions/source code I use before putting it to use, especially if I am to suggest it to someone else as that person just might want to know the benefits of using it and how it works.

Comment: Your source code is incorrect and your explanation has a spelling mistake. Please take your time to plan and write your answer. Spelling: **preventDefualt()** and the source code error: You never close the function  within the event listener `}`.

Comment: I see you have updated your answer but the spelling mistake is still in the description and you have placed the `}` in the wrong place so the source code is also still incorrect.

Comment: Now it is ok I think that , I use my iPhone so there were errors in the code and explanation, I hope that it will be good and working code